# No registra los datos insertados desde el formulario en la base de datos MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Hice un formulario en HTML y hasta ahí todo bien: conecté el código php con la base de datos y lo rellené, no me sale ningún error en el código pero voy a ver en la tabla de mi base de datos si se han insertado los datos y no aparece nada.

Este es el código php:

```
 <?php $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','cliente') or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

insertar($conexion); function insertar ($conexion){
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    $cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];

    $consulta = "INSERT INTO bdcliente(nombre, apellido, cedula, fecha, correo) 
    VALUES('$nombre','$apellido','$cedula','$fecha','$correo')" ;
    mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
    mysqli_close($conexion); } echo "Registrado" ?>
```

Este es el html:

La base de datos se llama *cliente* y la tabla se llama *bdcliente*. Este es el código sql:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Servidor: localhost
-- Tiempo de generación: 14-09-2022 a las 05:21:41
-- Versión del servidor: 5.5.16
-- Versión de PHP: 5.3.8

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"; SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */; /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */; /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */; /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `cliente`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `bdcliente`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bdcliente` (   `Idcliente` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `Nombre` varchar(20) NOT NULL,   `Apellido` varchar(20) NOT NULL,   `Cedula` varchar(10) NOT NULL,   `Fecha` date NOT NULL,   `Correo` varchar(40) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`Idcliente`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `bdcliente`
--

INSERT INTO `bdcliente` (`Idcliente`, `Nombre`, `Apellido`, `Cedula`, `Fecha`, `Correo`) VALUES (0, '', '', '', '', '');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */; /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */; /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Aquí faltó revisar qué salió en los logs de PHP. Posiblemente haya errores relacionados con que la consulta no tiene en cuenta ciertas caracteríßticas de la tabla...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idcliente es PK pero NO es autoincrementable, luego en el INSERT no le estas agregando Idcliente. O le agregas el id o lo haces autoincrementable:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bdcliente` ( 
`Idcliente` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Nombre` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`Apellido` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`Cedula` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`Fecha` date NOT NULL,
`Correo` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Idcliente`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

Comment: Y efectivamente ese era el problema puse null en el idcliente y ya me aparece los registros mediante el formulario muchas gracias bro.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es el campo `Fecha` en la creación de la tabla indicas

```
`Fecha` date NOT NULL,
```

Pero a la hora de ingresar datos el campo esta vacío, adicional a lo que indica @Yussef, asi que deberias decidir si pones el campo manualmente o dejas que MySQL lo ponga mediante `DATE(NOW())`, lo mismo sucede desde tu código PHP, antes de ingresar el campo `Fecha` debes verificar el formato de este campo en tu base de datos y al postearlo debes darle ese formato generalmente en la base es YYYY-MM-DD.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bdcliente`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bdcliente` ( 
`Idcliente` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Nombre` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`Apellido` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`Cedula` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`Fecha` date NOT NULL,
`Correo` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Idcliente`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;

INSERT
    INTO
    `bdcliente` (`Idcliente`,
    `Nombre`,
    `Apellido`,
    `Cedula`,
    `Fecha`,
    `Correo`)
VALUES (0,
'',
'',
'',
DATE(NOW()),
''
);
```